# getting 'using the in-browser JSX transformer. Be sure to precompile your JSX for production' when using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

getting "You are using the in-browser JSX transformer. Be sure to precompile your JSX for production - http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html#jsx" Error in browser console but application working fine using reactjs. how to remove this error?

Answer (score 1):

Well the issue is that rather than pre-compiling your JSX, you are having react parse it in the browser (hence the error message). The reason this is bad is that it is quite slow. To get rid of the error message I would look into the tooling it suggests in the link (I would recommend Babel) to compile your JSX in advance so the browser doesn't have to do it every single time. This will increase the performance of your page.

Comment: But when you add babel, you are getting this warning: "You are using the in-browser Babel transformer."

Comment: Right, you'd use babel to precompile your JS(X), don't use babel in the webpage as well